# How to know quantity of objects that has specific property in common?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

having an array of objects, how can I determine the quantity of objects that has a specific property in common?

for example:

```
[{"color": "red"},{"color": "red", "size": "big"},{"color": "red", "size": "big"}];
```

How can I get number of objects with property "size"?

Comment: You could perform a filter, and then get the length of the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `filter()` along with `hasOwnProperty()` to retrieve the objects in the array which have the `size` property. Then you can get the `length` to know how many there were.

```js
var arr = [{
  "color": "red"
}, {
  "color": "red",
  "size": "big"
}, {
  "color": "red",
  "size": "big"
}];

var result = arr.filter(x => x.hasOwnProperty('size'));
console.log(result.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array to return only those with key `size`, then use `.length` to show how many there are

```js
const myArray = [{
  "color": "red"
}, {
  "color": "red",
  "size": "big"
}, {
  "color": "red",
  "size": "big"
}];

const howManySize = myArray.filter(a => a.size).length;

console.log(howManySize);
```

Comment: attention: This will fail for `"size": ""` or `"size": 0`

Comment: Yes it will, agreed. I'm answering based on the OP, a point well made though.

Answer (score 0):

You could `.reduce` the array to the count of objects:

```
 array.reduce((count, el) => count + ("size" in el), 0)
```